# Adding custom permission to a role does not save

Tags: magento-2.1, acl

So I'm trying to write an ACL.XML file for a simple extension that we have that allows certain people to run a manual indexer.

However, all the documentation I can find says I should use:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::system">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::system_tools">
```

However if I use that, then the role never fully loads.

But if I change it to:

```
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::tools">
```

Then it loads, and I can add it to my role (add a checkmark) and click save. No errors. However, when I go back to the role resources, it's unchecked.

I'm completely new to ACL's in M2, so I'm a little stumped.

Here is a fully copy and paste of my ACL.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::system">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::tools">
                        <resource id="ProductIndexer::productindexer" title="Manual Indexer" sortOrder="60"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tools` is correct, not `system_tools`, as you can see in the original `acl.xml` of the `Magento_Backend` module: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/acl.xml#L39

But your own identifier `ProductIndexer::productindexer` is wrong. You cannot choose an arbitrary identifier, it must be in the form `Vendor_Module::name` (only the "name" part is arbitrary).